# amp-story-page last child

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-stories

It seems that **both** 'amp-story-cta-layer' and 'amp-story-page-attachment' have to be the **last child** of an 'amp-story-page' to validate. This is not possible. What can be done? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything; it is not possible to have both an `amp-story-cta-layer` and an `amp-story-page-attachment` on the same page of a story.